# Wheel Incompatibility between Python Minor Versions

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-packaging

I'm releasing a package on PyPi which will support Python 3.6+, and would like to build as few wheels as possible.

I've read up on [Python's packaging system for wheels](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/) and looked at the [NumPy project](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files) for an example. Reading [PEP 513](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) and [PEP 571](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0571/) was also insightful.

Here's the question: *why are wheels forwards-incompatible with Python minor version changes?*

Upgrading from 3.5 to 3.6, for example, brings f-strings. But it seems like a wheel built with Python 3.5 (not using f-strings) should be able to run just fine on a Python 3.6 environment. What's the issue here?

Comment: Python 3.5 code that runs in Python 3.6 is forward compatible, right? Python 3.6 code (without f-strings) would (maybe) be *backwards* compatible with Python 3.5. Do I have that backwards?

Comment: Correct. My question is, if my package runs fine on Python 3.5, do I need to release a 3.6 wheel as well, or will the 3.5 wheel suffice if the user is running 3.6? For example, NumPy is compatible with Python 3.5+, but they release wheels for each minor version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code written in pure Python in a 2-and-3 compatible way can be released in a universal wheel. One wheel that fits all Python versions. Example: https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/#files

But projects that include modules written in C must be released separately for every platform (processor architecture and 32/64-bitness), OS and Python version simply because the C code must be compiled differently. Example: https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/#files

PS. Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer for both projects used as examples.

Comment: Hmm, so every Python minor version compiles the C code differently?

Comment: Not necessary but the designers of `pip` and the binary wheel format decided not to risk and force new release for every minor Python version. It's simpler and less painful to release new wheel than to fix incompatibility.